# Update NetBeans manually

Tags: netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 8.2, I would like to update the plugins, but the firewall at work won't let me, they cannot seem to figure it out at work, so I was wondering how I can update it manually.

I found this link : http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDownloadingUCModule

But I cannot select my version there, the only version above 8.1 is dev, but when I select one of the options, I either get to a page I'm not allowed to access or a page mentioning : "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
 "

Is there another way to get the latest updates ?

Answer (score -1):

Just applying the correct proxy settings should allow you to download directly within netbeans.

Otherwise try downloading the plugins via [Plugin Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/).

Comment: Link no longer works